# HashTable with separate chaining and struct

Tags: c, hash-map

I'm pretty new to C and I'm trying to implement a hashtable with chaining for a struct I created:

HASH.h:

```
#ifndef HASH_H
#define HASH_H
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAXNAME 8000

/* Utilizing separate chaining and hashtables to
 * save the informations about objectives
 */

typedef struct {
   unsigned long int id, duration;
   char name [MAXNAME]; 
   unsigned long int *dep;
}Objective

typedef struct node{
   Objective objective;
   struct node*next;
}*link

void hashInit(int m);
link insertBegin(link head, Objective obj);
void objInsert(Objective obj);

#endif
```

HASH.c:

```
#include "HASH.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static link *heads;
static int M;

int hash(Key value, int m){
   return value%m;
}

void hashInit(int m){
   int i;
   M = m;
   heads = (link*)malloc(M*sizeof(link));
   for(i = 0; i < M; i++)
       heads[i] = NULL;
   }

link insertBegin(link head, Objective obj){
    link new = (link)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    new->value = obj;
    new->next = head;
    return new;
}

void objInsert(Objective obj){
   int i = hash(key(obj), M);
   heads[i] = insertBegin(heads[i], obj);
}
```

I'm still in the very beginning and don't have much but I'm just looking for advice on how and if I can improve what I did here, what I might have done wrong, and if I'm on the right path.

Comment: Does this even compile?  Those `typedef` declarations aren't terminated.